# How to prevent Python from disabling drop-down list in an existing excel workbook?

Tags: excel, pandas, dropdown, openpyxl

I have a short script to copy and paste a few dataframes into an existing excel workbook.  However, after pasting the data, my drop-down lists in the excel workbook all got turned off.  Is there any way to stop Python from disabling drop-down lists in the existing excel?  My script is as follows:

from openpyxl import load_workbook

```
model_path=path  #path to an existing workbook
book = load_workbook(model_path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(model_path, engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, 'tab1', startcol=0, startrow=3, index=False)   
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Tab1 is currently empty. After the data is pasted in by Python, it is used as data source where other worksheets draw upon.  Tab1 has no drop down lists.  Only other sheets have them.  But pasting in data in tab1 would disable them for some reason.

Comment: What do you mean by "drop down lists"? Those are somewhat ambiguous in Excel since they can mean data validations, embedded form controls, or embedded ActiveX controls. Also, what do you mean by disabled? A [mcve] which instructions for how to create a very simple example workbook would help.

Comment: By "drop down list" I mean data validation.  I presented my codes above.  For the excel workbook, there is nothing special.  Just have my code write to one of the sheets and have any drop down list in another worksheet.  Run my code then watch if the drop down list get disable.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't have time to think about it today, but if I have time later this week I'll play around with it since I am interested in Python/Excel interaction